# Questions regarding a project -- should I be making new questions or editing old ones?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, asking-questions

I've been working on this tree project and I've been having a lot of trouble adapting to the d3 library. I'm learning very fast but I feel sometimes if I really can't figure it out (this is after heavy Google searching and trying lots of things) I end up asking a question just so I don't waste time.

However, because all the questions do involve D3 Trees, I feel I may be making too many questions... when exactly should I be editing a question and when should I be making a new one? I feel all the questions are different, but can be tweaked to be similar... Thoughts on this?

Here are some of my questions:

[D3 How to zoom in on SVG text that stays within an SVG Rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497856/d3-how-to-zoom-in-on-svg-text-that-stays-within-an-svg-rectangle)

[D3 Tree layout: How to fill rectangles with text, but have them in uniform size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349467/d3-tree-layout-how-to-fill-rectangles-with-text-but-have-them-in-uniform-size)

[D3 Tree Layout Separation Between Nodes using NodeSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558649/d3-tree-layout-separation-between-nodes-using-nodesize)

Like I said they are similar but also different... They encompass different parts of my project but all work together to help me accomplish it. I try go about things step-by-step because this is a learning experience for me. I do try a lot of things and do some research before I post on SO but I don't want to be spamming SO with too many questions. Thanks guys.

Comment: Your questions look fine to me... Above average question quality, I'd say.

Comment: I would not edit your old ones to further add new problems, etc.  Posting a new question when you are moving along in your project and find new problems is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As mentioned in the comments] Do not modify existing questions (especially answered ones) *unless you are clarifying or adding context to the existing question.*

Do not be concerned that the questions are on a very similar topic as long as they are distinctly different questions about that same topic. Be prepared for the occasional *Close as duplicate* vote that points to one of your previous questions as the duplicate - sometimes people are a little trigger happy, in this case you simply need to add a comment about why it's not a duplicate.

Also don't be overly concerned about question quantity, just make sure you maintain the quality of each question. You don't know how many other people out there have had (or will have) the same problems as you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications :) I shall continue to ask away :P